# Is it possible to create responsive top navigation menu with Onsen UI?

Tags: responsive-design, navigation, onsen-ui

I mean something like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_topnav)

It looks like neither `ons-navigator` nor `ons-splitter` can provide such behavior. 
Any ideas? Probably combining some components together?

Answer (score 0):

Nahh onsen a framework geared toward mobile applications. I would look into bootstrap, bootstrap has a navbar like that